# Apple iCal's "Delegation" tab -- disabled checkboxes?

Tags: icalendar, caldav

I am trying to access a CalDAV account in iCal and everything works fine except for the Delegation tab. I can see the account(s) I have access to (including the correct read/write properties), but the checkboxes are disabled and the calendars cannot be selected. Has anyone seen this before & know what the cause is?

This is a custom CalDAV implementation, so it is likely due to a disconnect between what iCal expects and what our server is sending -- but there are no error/warning messages in the console to indicate what the problem might be.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You might try an off-topic but polite post to the [official IRC channel for DAViCal](irc://irc.oftc.net/#davical).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCal queries the permissions and methods available on the server.  To query the permissions on a collection resource you will need to have the DAV::read-current-user-privilege-set permission.  Assuming iCal can read the permissions it will be looking for the DAV::read permission for reading and the DAV::bind, DAV::unbind and DAV::write permissions to indicate the ability to write.

The best way to debug this is probably to read RFC3744 about half a dozen times, interspersed with using iCal against a working server and sniffing the TCP communication as it does it. A good way is to use some kind of man-in-the-middle proxy so you can sniff the communication with (e.g.) Mobile Me or iCloud.

Comment: Yes, that's it.  I should have updated this question with the solution I found, but it was essentially this; we had a very minor syntax error in the XML (IIRC, an extraneous trailing '/' for the princial-url) in one location of the response and that was causing this behavior.  I spent dozens of hours pouring over the XML char by char to find it.  I was so annoyed I didn't want to come back here!  ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience, this happens when the account used for sharing is functional (not personal) in Microsoft Exchange Server 2010. An example, where two of three are functional:

[image: screenshot of preferences for delegation for an Exchange account in iCal]

I do use various CalDAV implementations but have never encountered the same limitation, so this may be not a good answer. Also Exchange Web Services (EWS) for calendaring and delegation are probably not comparable to CalDAV. Still, it's food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

The **Debug** menu of iCal 5.x offers CalDAV logging options.

To enable that menu, you could use the [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) preference pane.